# EF - taking X elements after a specific element in a sorted query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

A `Chat` has `Messages`.  Given a `MessageId`, I'm trying to get the next 50 messages.  What I have now should work in theory, but it's very inefficient as I'm loading everything into memory.  Here's what I have so far:

```
            // get message with parent chat / other messages
            var message = db.ChatMessages.Include(s => s.Chat.Messages).First(s => s.ChatMessageId == messageId);
            var chat = message.Chat;

            // this is what I want to avoid, but I don't know how to get the position without throwing all messages into memory
            var messages = chat.Messages.OrderByDescending(s => s.DatePosted).ToList();
            var index = messages.IndexOf(message);
            messages = messages.GetRange(index, index + 50);
            return messages.ToList();
```

How can I perform this operation without throwing every message into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the Id of the last message (or something else unique), this becomes simpler. Assuming the Ids are always incrementing...

```
var messages = chat.Messages.
                    Where(s=>s.Id > LastMessage.Id).
                    OrderByDescending(s => s.DatePosted).
                    Take(50);
```

If you don't have always incrementing Ids...

```
var messages = chat.Messages.
                    Where(s=>s.DatePosted > LastMessage.DatePosted).
                    OrderByDescending(s => s.DatePosted).
                    Take(50);
return messages.ToList();
```

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is this ToList():  `var messages = chat.Messages.OrderByDescending(s => s.DatePosted).ToList();` - or is it unavoidable?

Comment: See my edit - I think that helps? And sorry, yes, I skimmed the question and added that as an afterthought when it was the thrust of your question. Apologies

Comment: Ah, basing it off the id is a clever solution.  I think it works!  Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Is the second approach much less performant than the first?  I feel more comfortable using DateTime instead of Id, as I'm not sure I can rely on the Id.

Comment: It depends on the database. Ids are almost always primary keys and are thus tied to the order the data is physically stored in. Dates aren't usually (by default) indexed at all so would require a table scan (very slow). You could improve this by making an index against the date - meaning you should get a table seek which should be not much worse than the primary key (but not quite as good). I strongly recommend you take the SQL it generates, and have a look at the Execution plan using SQL Management Studio - you should be able to see ow it's handled and where the time is spent